# How to generate a logarithmic spaced array in C

Tags: c, arrays, vector, spacing

I am trying to generate an logarithmic spaced array in C.

For example, starting at 100 and ending at 500, with 40 logarithmic spaced points.

Can anyone help me? Are there any logspace() functions available?

Answer (score 5):

With no further constraints, simply divide the linear interval [ln(100)..ln(500)] into as much subintervals (equidistant) as you need. Then take the exp() of each point.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays always use linear, integer and n+1 stepping. So you have to map the logarithmic scale to the linear index. This can be done either by simply taking log(log_index) or a table of ranges and a linear search in that. For log(), there might be approximations which suit your needs better and are faster than a full-grown (float) logarithm function.

You might for instance take the number of the uppermost 1-bit in the log-index and use the next n lower bits as range-index:

```
// all vars are size_t (unsigned at least!)
base_index = get_number_of_uppermost_bit(log_index);
shift = (base_index > 3U) ? (base_index - 3U) : 0;
lin_index = base_index * 8U + ((log_index >> shift) & (8U-1U);
```

The values of 8 and 3 (ld(8)) are the number of entries per log-range. Note these are linear (sometimes an acceptable approximation). You can also apply the algorithm to the lower bits, however getting an integer log function. But the above is faster and might be sufficient. Alternatively, you can use a lookup table for the lower 3 bits.
A decimal stepping would be more difficult that way and pretty inefficient.